# phpStorm подсветка HTML - как сделать, чтобы внутренний тег div подсвечивался таким же цветом, как и внешний? Я цвет указал, а он прозрачнее

Tags: phpstorm

Вот, что сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы хотел, чтобы внутренний тег div, когда я поставил на него каретку, подсвечивался таким же ярким желтым цветом, как и внешний (как в Netbeans). В настройках я указал яркий желтый цвет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но он почему-то прозранч

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поиграть с величиной **opacity** в **Settings | Editor | General | Appearance, Enable XML/HTML tag tree highlighting**; `0.7`, скажем, делает их отменно яркими:)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]